# Repeat last test in debug mode in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: debug, visual-studio-2013

It is possible to repeat the last test, but in *debug* mode?

When running the last test (even when I manually last ran it in debug mode), it will run without debug mode.

I thought perhaps I could map a shortcut key to an underlying command. However using the command window, I cannot see a command suggesting that it can be done.

[image: repeat last run]

[image: test in debug mode]

Comment: Can someone with more reputation add a unit testing tag to this, it would be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joshu Weber at Microsoft said the following when the [same question](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/752020/repeat-last-run-test-explorer-doesnt-work-correctly) was asked on Microsoft Connect:

> Andrew,
>
> This is very interesting feedback. We designed the repeat last run command as a shortcut to selecting a subset of all your tests for execution. It currently by design does not take into account debug attachment as part of a run. This is a interesting new feature idea however and >we are going to place it on our backlog.
>
> Thanks for the feedback. Keep it coming.
>   Joshua Weber

In other words it seems like this isn't possible at the moment (without on add-on at least).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible using ReSharper. Look for the `ReSharper.ReSharper_UnitTestSessionRepeatPreviousRun` command in the keyboard bindings options. It can repeat the last test run in debug mode.

Comment: resharper requires a local cluster to work OK